# Chained Promises not fully resolving on await

Tags: javascript, loops, csv, promise, chained

I have a function that reads files in a directory asynchronously (readdir) and filters for csv files. I also have an async function that calls readdir filtered for csv files and then iterates through them with fast-csv. Logging to the console the list and its length within the .on('end') function, I can see that they produce the desired results. however, my async call only resolves the first iteration.

```
const fs = require(`fs`);
const path = require(`path`);
const csv = require(`fast-csv`);
var ofsActivities = [];

const currDir = path.join(__dirname + `/../Downloads/`);

const readdir = async dirname => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(dirname, (error, filenames) => {
        error ? reject(error) : resolve(filenames);
      });
  });
};

const filtercsvFiles = (filename) => {
  return filename.split(`.`)[1] == `csv`;
};

const ofsDataObjectArray = async () => {
  return readdir(currDir).then(async filenames => {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      filenames = filenames.filter(filtercsvFiles);
      for (let i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
        let currFilePath = currDir + filenames[i];
        console.log(`Reading File: ${filenames[i]}`);
        csv
          .parseFile(currFilePath)
          .on(`data`, (data) => {
            //Doing stuff
          })
          .on(`error`, error => reject(error))
          .on(`end`, () => resolve(ofsActivities)); //Inserting a console.log(ofsActivities.length) logs the correct and expected length on the last iteration
      }
    });
  });
};

(async () => {
  let list = await ofsDataObjectArray(); // This seems to only resolve the first iteration within the promise
  console.log(list.length);
})();
```

Comment: There is `fs/promises` for quite a while now. So you don't need to promisify the callback based functions yourself.

Comment: And for your problem: I suppose "doing stuff" also is pushing into the `ofsActivities` array? But you are resolving your `Promise` once the *first* csv parsing is calling the `.on("end", ...)` callback. So the array only contains one element. But of course the loop continues even after you call `resolve`. So you see the correct length logged eventually. But as `resolve` has been already called multiple times, anything that is waiting for this promise already got a value. You probably want to call `resolve` that only after *all* files finished ...

Comment: @derpirscher, yes, doing stuff is pushing to an array based on the data parsed in each file. I had a feeling that my initial resolve call during the first iteration of the for loop was the heart of the issue. Would a barbaric approach work? If(i == filenames.length - 1) { resolve(ofsActivities) } within the .on(`end`)? This is my first attempt at async functions and have only been familiar with js for about 6 months lol

Comment: You need to call `resolve()` only when the LAST `csv.parseFile()` is done.  You're calling it when the FIRST one is done, thus the promise doesn't wait for all the others to complete.  I'd suggest you promisify `csv.parseFile()` by itself and then `await` that inside the loop or accumulate all the promises from `csv.parseFile()` and use `Promise.all()` with all of them.

Comment: Assuming that there will be one element for every file in `ofsActivities` you should check `if (of activities.length == filename.length) resolve(ofsActivities)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `resolve()` only when the LAST `csv.parseFile()` is done. You're calling it when the FIRST one is done, thus the promise doesn't wait for all the others to complete. I'd suggest you promisify `csv.parseFile()` by itself and then await that inside the loop or accumulate all the promises from `csv.parseFile()` and use `Promise.all()` with all of them.

Here's using `await` on each `csv.parseFile()`:

```
const ofsDataObjectArray = async () => {
    return readdir(currDir).then(async filenames => {
        filenames = filenames.filter(filtercsvFiles);
        for (let i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
            let currFilePath = currDir + filenames[i];
            console.log(`Reading File: ${filenames[i]}`);
            await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                csv.parseFile(currFilePath)
                    .on(`data`, (data) => {
                        //Doing stuff
                    })
                    .on(`error`, reject)
                    .on(`end`, () => resolve(ofsActivities)); 
            });
        }
        return ofsActivities;
    });
};
```

Or, here's running them in parallel with `Promise.all()`:

```
const ofsDataObjectArray = async () => {
    return readdir(currDir).then(filenames => {
        filenames = filenames.filter(filtercsvFiles);
        return Promise.all(filenames.map(file => {
            let currFilePath = currDir + file;
            console.log(`Reading File: ${file}`);
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                csv.parseFile(currFilePath)
                    .on(`data`, (data) => {
                        //Doing stuff
                    })
                    .on(`error`, error => reject(error))
                    .on(`end`, () => resolve(ofsActivities)); 
            });

        }))
    });
};
```

P.S. It's unclear from your question what final result you're trying to accumulate (you have left that out) so you will have to add that to this code in the "doing stuff" code or by modifying the `resolve(something)` code.